# How to prevent stack from downloading GHC for every new project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How to prevent stack from downloading GHC for every new project?

Every time I create a new project using stack and then build or exec the codes, stack will install a new GHC for me. This is not only boring for waiting such a long time for a huge image to be downloaded (behind the GFW, xKib/s), but also a space disaster for my pity 128G SSD Macbook Pro. How can I fix this?

```
$ stack exec blah
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
ghc-8.4.4:   15.98 KiB / 220.05 MiB (  0.01%) downloaded...^C
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack only installs a new ghc if the stack.yaml you are using requires some ghc version that you do not yet have installed via stack. Once stack has installed ghc-8.4.4, for example, it will not reinstall this version of ghc.

I would presume the solution, then, is to make sure you are using the same resolver for all of your projects, so that stack only installs the one ghc version.

Comment: It might be worth it mentioning the `--resolver` option explicitly,

Answer (score 4):

Just find `$HOME/.stack.yaml` and add:

```
# Turn on system GHC
system-ghc: true
```

and run the same command again.

Comment: Looks like things have changed, this now goes in ~/.stack/config.yaml. You will also need to change `resolver` in your project's `stack.yaml` to be `resolver: ghc-8.8.2` or whatever matches `ghc --version`